# which type of ANN should I use?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a project in which I have to predict the methane production

input:pH,temperature,solution concentration
output: methene production

I have used Keras TensorFlow

my questions are:

1. (as of now I have 60 experimental data) the accuracy is always 0.2-0.3 why?should I increase te number of data?
2. I used the following code:

```
classifier.add(Dense(6, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform',input_dim=9))
classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer= 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

3.It is possible to predict other than binary outputs, right? if no then which one will be suitable for predicting non binary values

Comment: Deep Learning models do not work well with very limited amounts of data. Either augment the data or get more data to see better results.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 60 data points, yes definitely try to get more data. In general it is good to have hundreds (if not thousands) of data points to effectively train a neural network. Your network looks fine (assuming the relationship between those inputs and the output is fairly linear), if that is not the case you could try making your hidden layer wider (more neurons).

It is definitely possible to predict other than binary outputs, in fact it looks like your network should be doing so. It really just depends on the activation function you put on your output layer. For example, [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) is good for classifying data when there are several possible labels. For binary classification, a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) activation function is good. If you're just trying to predict an output quantity, you can probably just not have an activation function on your output.

Answer (score 0):

yes have to provide more data to learn the pattern in data points, if have linear regression than used it for better

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).